# In Maya, is there a way to grab positional camera attributes (rotation, translation) during tumbling?

Tags: python, maya

I'm working on a script that will record some of the user's actions and play them back, right now just focused on perspective camera movement.  By using the scriptJob command, I'm able to capture camera attributes once they're set, but my ideal script would capture all camera movement during the tumble itself.  Is there a way to do this?

The current script looks something like this:

```
def startRecording():
    cmds.scriptJob(attributeChange=["persp.rotate", recordValuesAtTime])
    cmds.scriptJob(attributeChange=["persp.translate", recordValuesAtTime])

def playback():
    for e in events:
        # lerp from starting position to next position for each event
```

Comment: Keyframing the camera is out of the question?

Comment: important little tidbit, do you want to record the movement for animation, in other words motion capture. Or for some other purpose.See maya has since version 1 a recording playback mode. Hovever it records with fixed sampling rate and that may or may not be what you want. This info affects the answer. In either case this is pretty simple stuff to do, but scriptjobs are the wrong tool for this ( or events in general)

Comment: @joojaa this is intended to be for tutorials, so the instructor can record what they're doing in Maya and then the student can play it back in their own instance

Comment: autodresk used to have a tool for this kind of recording it  was free, so ask them also. Ill device an answer later because i can not use mayas graphical user interface easily with my phone ( i can use  maya cmd tough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost have it. You just need the right triggering event in the scriptJob setup (in MEL):

```
scriptJob -event ($triggerEvent) recordVauesAtTime;
```

Where $triggerEvent is possibly *cameraChange* or *glFrameTrigger*.  You can get a list of events using (also MEL):

```
$list = `scriptJob -listEvents`;
for ($it in $list) {
  print ($it+"\n");
}
```

Would be trial and error finding what works best and be warned, some might really slam Maya with a slew of events.